# Converting any CSS colour to RGB(a)

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin

For a plugin I'm writing in jQuery, I have two optional parameters. For each parameter I do a check for its value. However, I'm curious if I can't write it shorter.

[jsFiddleiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/qog37z7g/)

```
(function ($) {
    $.rgbGenerator = function (color, options) {
        var args = $.extend({
            returnAsObj: false,
            addAlpha: false
        }, options);

        var d = $("<div>");
        d.css("color", color).appendTo("body");
        var rgb = d.css("color");
        rgb = rgb.replace(/(^rgba?\(|\)$|\s)/g, "").split(",").map(Number);
        d.remove();
        if (args.addAlpha === false) {
            if (rgb.length == 3) {
                if (!args.returnAsObj === true) {
                    return "rgb(" + rgb[0] + "," + rgb[1] + "," + rgb[2] + ")";
                } else {
                    return {
                        r: rgb[0],
                        g: rgb[1],
                        b: rgb[2]
                    };
                }
            } else if (rgb.length == 4) {
                if (!args.returnAsObj === true) {
                    return "rgba(" + rgb[0] + "," + rgb[1] + "," + rgb[2] + "," + rgb[3] + ")";
                } else {
                    return {
                        r: rgb[0],
                        g: rgb[1],
                        b: rgb[2],
                        a: rgb[3]
                    };
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (!args.returnAsObj === true) {
                return "rgba(" + rgb[0] + "," + rgb[1] + "," + rgb[2] + "," + args.addAlpha + ")";
            } else {
                return {
                    r: rgb[0],
                    g: rgb[1],
                    b: rgb[2],
                    a: args.addAlpha
                };
            }
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Basically, what it does is:

1. Check `args.addAlpha` whether it's false (default)
2. Check the length of `rgb` (when it's 3 it's RGB, when it's 4 it's rgba)
3. Check `args.returnAsObj`. If it's set to true, return an object rather than a string

Especially the part where I check the length of `rgb` seems unnecessary, but I'm not sure how I could write it any other way. Something like this would be nice:

```
return {
    r: rgb[0],
    g: rgb[1],
    b: rgb[2],
    a: function () {
        if (rgb.length == 4 || !args.addAlpha === false) {
            return rgb[3] || args.addAlpha;
        }
    }
};
```

But I assume that's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that returning an object where `a` is a function would not work, but it would work to return the result of a call to a function!

You can also restructure things a bit to reduce duplicated code. By having a starting string or a starting object, and optionally adding to that string or object if some conditions are fulfilled.

This is untested code, but I think it should do the same as your original.

```
function result(addAlpha, rgb, asObject) {
    if (asObject) {
        var obj = { r: rgb[0], g: rgb[1], b: rgb[2] };
        if (addAlpha !== false) {
            obj.a = addAlpha;
        }
        else if (rgb.length == 4) {
            obj.a = rgb[3];
        }
        return obj;
    }

    var a = (addAlpha !== false) || (rgb.length == 4) ? "a" : "";
    var alpha = "";
    if (addAlpha !== false) alpha = "," + addAlpha;
    else if (rgb.length == 4) alpha = "," + rgb[3];
    return "rgb" + a + "(" + rgb[0] + "," + rgb[1] + "," + rgb[2] + alpha + ")";
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to keep this in the plugin format?

Comment: @BramVanroy I am sure it is, somehow, but that goes outside the scope of my answer. Otherwise you can just copy the contents of the `result` method I have written here to your `$.rgbGenerator = function (color, options) {`

Comment: Thank you, after some fiddling I got it to work. Thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/qog37z7g/